# Azure "Deployment successful" but app URL yields ":( Application Error" ... Docker ... container start failures

Tags: azure, deployment

I am developing an Angular app with vscode on windows 10. It runs well locally.

I have tried to deploy it to Azure.

The vscode OUTPUT console says:

```
8:54:39 AM XXXXXXYY: Deployment successful.
8:54:36 AM: Deployment to "XXXXXXYY" completed.
```

Browsing to the app URL yields `:( Application Error`

The Azure *Application Logs* say:

```
...
2020-02-17T18:02:12.322797181Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2020-02-17T18:02:12.322800881Z 
2020-02-17T18:02:12.322804281Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2020-02-17T18:02:12.322807781Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2020-02-17T18:02:12.322811381Z NodeJS Version : v12.13.0

...

2020-02-17T18:03:50.224589935Z ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
Docker on instance: RD0004FFE4001B experienced container start failures.
```

I *didn't knowingly request a Docker container*.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: getting same issues going through terraform tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/provision-infrastructure-azure-pipelines/8-run-terraform-pipeline

Answer (score 1):

From your description, you could run an Angular app on windows 10 well locally. So, it recommended to deploy it on Azure app service on Windows instead of Linux as the logged.

You could follow this blog: [How to Deploy an Angular application to Azure Web Service](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/deploy-angular-application-on-azure-web-service-960e441bb13d) to create a windows OS app service. For using VScode deployment, refer to [this](https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-an-angular-app-from-visual-studio-code-to-a-1).

Hope it could help you.